# iPhones copy paste menu gets closed when updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, mobile-safari

I have an order page with a countdown which tells the user how much time he has left to complete his order. We spotted that when the user wants to paste something into an input field and opens this context menu for it, the menu will close each time the timer updates.

[image: Copy paste menu on iOS]

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("EvTest", []);
app.controller("TestController", function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.counter = 1;
  $interval(function() {
    $scope.counter++;
  }, 1000);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <input type="text" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Test me!" />
  {{counter}}
</div>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bojarhwt/

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is this an issue only on safari or on other browsers too?

Comment: Seems to be iOS only

Comment: Yes but on iOS does it happens on iOS chrome too?

Comment: Oh - sorry. After testing it out it seems to be a Safari only problem.

Comment: Whats the version of iOS that you are using?

Comment: Currently it is 8.2. Will update to 8.3 and test it again.

Comment: Yes i think so this issue is with the browser itself and its not related to your coding in js/html/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved with updating to iOS 8.3. Apparently it was a bug in Safari.